# Nested classes that inherit from the outer parent's nested classes in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, class-method

Suppose I have the following class in Python 3:

```
class CoolCar:
    @classmethod
    def myWheels(cls):
        cls.Wheels().out()
    class Wheels:
        def __init__(self):
            self.s = "I'm round!"
        def out(self):
            print(self.s)
```

All well and good.  Now I want a derived class:

```
class TerribleTank(CoolCar):
    class Wheels(CoolCar.Wheels):
        def __init__(self):
            self.s = "I'm square!!"
```

This works as I would expect:

```
CoolCar.myWheels()
TerribleTank.myWheels()
```

But what's bothering me is that I have to write `CoolCar` twice in the definition of `TerribleTank`. So I tried this:

```
class TerribleTank(CoolCar):
    class Wheels(super().Wheels):
        def __init__(self):
            self.s = "I'm square!!"
```

Which does not work. Now, I know it doesn't work because `super()` is looking for a first-argument `self`/`cls` to begin its search.

So finally my question: Is there something like this that works, so that I don't need to explicitly write that second `CoolCar`?

Comment: why are you putting classes in classes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: this is a greatly simplified example of what is actually going on.  I am using subclasses for various reasons (namespace issues one of them), but also because it allows me to write `Wheels.foo` in one of my classes, and it simply works, with the right version of Wheels.  For more information, please see the Factory Pattern chapter in Marc Summfield's *Python in Practice*.

Comment: Just declare Wheels as a class within the module, rather than encapsulating inside Coolcar.  Surely Uncoolcars are entitled to wheels as well?

Comment: @JohnMee: `TerribleTank` will override this Wheel class.  Now what does any class that inherits from `TerribleTank` do? Putting the original `Wheels` class at the module level only raises the problem one generation, it does not solve it.

Comment: I at least cannot see any way to use super how you want, Wheels knows nothing about CoolCar

Comment: Do you appreciate that, in the example that works as you expect, you haven't actually instantiated a Coolcar or a TerribleTank, and are effectly just running a staticmethod?

Comment: @johnmee: Yes that is by design. In the actual code these are factory classes, not meant to be instantiated.

Comment: For this kind of problem, I would probably be calling `type(name, bases, dict)` to construct classes programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
class CoolCar:
    @classmethod
    def myWheels(cls):
        cls.Wheels().out()
    class Wheels:
        def __init__(self):
            self.s = "I'm round!"
        def out(self):
            print(self.s)

class TerribleTank(CoolCar):
    class Wheels(TerribleTank.Wheels):
        def __init__(self):
            self.s = "I'm square!!"

>>> TerribleTank.myWheels()
I'm square!!
```

basically when you inherit `CoolCar` in `TerribleTank`, you set up `TerribleTank.Wheels` as a reference to `CoolCar.Wheels`, until you shadow it with your own new definition of it within the `TerribleTank` definition. So I believe that matches your expectations of not having `CoolCar` twice in TerribleBank definition ☺

HTH

Comment: N.B.: If you're still unhappy about this because of the use of `TerribleBank` twice, you might try using metaclasses, but personally I'd rather go to bed than over-engineering something that simple ;)

Comment: Tweak it to call `TerribleTank.myWheels()` directly, he doesn't want to create tanks or cars; just their wheels.

Comment: This is technically correct (the best kind of correct), but I still hold hope there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: well, the cleaner way is what you suggested but does not fit you, this is what comes second, and then you might use some metaclass mess. But there's a saying: when you got a problem that needs metaclass to be solved, you end up having a metaproblem ;-)